# Python Syntax Error is not being caught

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

```
from __future__ import print_function

try:
    print "a"
except SyntaxError:
    print('error')
```

Why is the `SyntaxError` exception not being caught? I am using Python 2.7

Output:

```
  File "test", line 4
    print "a"
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You can't catch syntax error

Comment: @BhargavRao: yes, you can. Just *not in the file with the error*.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot catch the syntax error in the module itself, because it is thrown **before the code is run**. Python doesn't run the code as it is compiled line by line, it is the *whole file* that failed here.

You can do this:

`syntaxerror.py`

```
from __future__ import print_function

print "a"
```

`catching.py`:

```
from __future__ import print_function

try:
    import syntaxerror
except SyntaxError:
    print('Error')
```

because the `catching` script can be run after compiling, but trying to import `syntaxerror` then triggers a new compilation task on `syntaxerror.py`, raising a `SyntaxError` exception which then can be caught.